# find the number of one-to-one function $[\pm n] \rightarrow [\pm n]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

the permutaion of $[\pm n]$ is a bijective (one-to-one) function $\pi:[\pm n] \rightarrow [\pm n]$ so that $\pi (-i) = -\pi(i)$ . $[\pm n]:=\{1, \dots, n, -1, \dots, -n\}$.
i have to find and determine the number of such permutaion of $[\pm n]$.

Answer (score 0):

A permutation of a set $A$ is a bijection between $A$ and itself; you're looking for *special* permutations of $[\pm n]$ that are odd in the sense of functions (not in the permutation sense). Let's call the set of these "odd bijections" $\hat{S}_n$.

For $\sigma \in \hat{S}_n$, and define

\begin{align*}
\lvert \sigma \rvert : [n] &\to [n] \\
 i &\mapsto \lvert \sigma(i) \rvert.
\end{align*}

You can verify that $\lvert \sigma \rvert$ is a permutation of $[n]$ whenever $\sigma \in \hat{S}_n$.

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\hat{S}_n$, declaring $\sigma_1 \sim \sigma_2$ if $\lvert \sigma_1 \rvert = \lvert \sigma_2 \rvert$ for $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in \hat{S}_n$. Study this equivalence relation to find the size of $\hat{S}_n$.

(Note: There is another, possibly more straightforward way to go about it, but if you had played around with small $n$, you'd probably have found it by now)

Comment: if $\sigma=a_1 a_2\dots a_n$ then for $a_1$ i have n possible choices for $a_2$ n-1 ... thats mean that i have n! or 2n! because |$\sigma$| !?

Comment: You're on the right track, but you're not quite there yet. I'll give you a hint: When $n = 3$, you have $48$ such permutations. Try and write down some of the more interesting ones.

Comment: why 48 ? if n=3  then i have 6! (like $\sigma=$123-1-2-3) or ?

Comment: \begin{align*}\sigma: [\pm 3] &\to [\pm 3]\\1 &\mapsto -1\\ -1 &\mapsto 1\\2 &\mapsto 3\\ -2 &\mapsto -3\\3 &\mapsto -2\\ -3 &\mapsto 2\end{align*} is one of the "more interesting" maps I was referring to, one of the $48$ total when $n = 3$. In this case, $\lvert \sigma \rvert$ is the ordinary permutation $(1\ 3\ 2)$ of $[3]$. Now just spend some time getting comfortable with the objects in question.